# Azure Wordpress charging after being deleted

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-webapps, azure-mysql-database

I deployed my WordPress website on the azure web-app. MYSQL Server for WordPress started charging a crazy amount of money. I stopped MySQL server initially but it didn't help. Then I deleted the resource group altogether, but MySQL server instance is still eating away money from azure. Can anyone tell me what is the correct way to clear this.

Comment: you should contact billing support (its always free), but if you truly deleted the service - you cant be billed for it

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think the database is still incurring costs? Visit [Cost Analysis under Cost management in the Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_CostManagement/Menu/costanalysis) and check to make sure the costs you're seeing aren't from before you deleted the resource group.

If something is actually still costing money, create a new (billing) support request under [Help + support | New support request](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/newsupportrequest).

To make sure there aren't any other resources somewhere that are causing these costs, check [All resources](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseAll) in the Azure portal.